# How to create a Spring web app on a server

Tags: java, spring

Firstly, please excuse my horrendously general question, as my understanding of Spring is very limited, but I will expalin what I want to achieve, and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have an application that retrieves some information from some source and updates a database. I'd like to put this program on a Tomcat server, so that the application is run every day.

I'm very new to Spring, and have spent the last few days completing some basic tutorials to display Hello World! in a broswer.

However, all of the tutorials I have found relate to Controllers for URLs, which, as far as I understand, is not what I want, as my application will not have a URL and there will be nothing to display, I just want the application to "hidden" somewhere on the server, and to execute daily.

I know this is a very general question, and as I said my knowledge of Spring is next to non-existent, so I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, I'll happily do research if I just knew what to look for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should still tick the "spring-web" box so that the application stays alive after being started, but otherwise that means you need to use the spring servlet initializer (which is described somewhere in the docs how to create a Spring Boot WAR file) and then use `@Scheduled` annotation to define your task that should run on specific intervals (or a CRON trigger or something like that)

Comment: Seems you need use spring do some scheduled tasks. See this https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: With what you want for your application i would not choose a J2EE + Spring environnement ... as Spring was made for managing Url Mapping and Forms. You should look for a different server langage imo

Comment: How about Spring boot?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, the scheduled task is not the part I'm having a problem with, I've looked into scheduled tasks and I have a method that works correctly. My problem is the intermediary step of uploading the program to the Tomcat server using Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) quite easy to start with and does all the magic for you.

There are few tutorials how to start and what you will need.

You can have a jar that will run on embedded Tomcat server provided by spring boot, or you can convert it then to a war/ear file and deploy it on External Tomcat if you wish (doesn't need to be tomcat either). You just need a deployable artefact. In this case a war or ear.

[Difrence between jar, war, ear](http://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/answer/What-are-the-differences-between-Ear-Jar-and-War-files)

if you then wish to convert it:
[Convert a jar into a war](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)

[Deploying Spring boot apps on External servers](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications)

All the documentation you can find on [Spring guides](https://spring.io/guides)

Answer (score 0):

Spring is a very frustrating framework to learn because of all the various versions and tools out there.

[Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) is usually the starting point for people since it creates an executable self-contained JAR with embeded Tomcat server.

If you want to run with your own Tomcat instance, you need to look into creating a `WAR/EAR` file, which is an archive with a directory named `WEB-INF` that contains all of your Tomcat XML configurations.

[Turn your Jar into a War](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)

One of the simplest ways to start is to use Maven, add the WAR plugin to your `pom.xml` file, then `webapp/WEB-INF` directory to your project and place the `web.xml` config file in it.

[Create and deploy web apps on Tomcat](https://wiki.base22.com/btg/how-to-create-a-maven-web-app-and-deploy-to-tomcat-fast-27033760.html)

Comment: How is that simplest way? And you don't need to place web.xml nor create it by yourself. Simply create a spring-boot application and you can either deploy it to tomcat or run as a stand alone application. Since you don't really need access to any controller, you don't really need any configuration. Spring will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to put this program on a Tomcat server, so that the application is run every day.

Seems to me that you don't really need Tomcat or Spring.

Why not just install your Java app on a UNIX server and have it run every day with cron ?